# How to consume a conduit with WAI (raw request body)

Tags: haskell, monads, conduit, haskell-wai

I'm using scotty, which is a sinatra-like wrapper around WAI. I want to get the raw request body as a byte string so I can parse it as json. The following is close. This is similar to other questions about consuming a body using WAI, but is different because I want the body as a bytestring, and because I'm in a different monad, ActionM

```
import Network.Wai (requestBody)
import Web.Scotty (ActionM, request, text)

bodyExample :: ActionM ()
bodyExample = do
    r <- request
    bss <- requestBody r -- this needs a lift or something
    text "ok"
    ...
```

It obviously won't work, I think I need some kind of lift or something, but I don't know what to use. `liftIO` isn't right, and `lift` gives me weird errors.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/scotty/0.0.1/doc/html/Web-Scotty.html

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/wai/latest/doc/html/Network-Wai.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestBody` isn't a monadic value. It is simply a function that returns a Conduit `Source IO ByteString`.

To consume the source, use [`Data.Conduit.List.consume`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/latest/doc/html/Data-Conduit-List.html#v%3aconsume) (or [`Data.Conduit.Lazy.lazyConsume`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/0.1.1.1/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Lazy.html#v%3alazyConsume)). You will get a list of `ByteString`s as the result. To then exit the `ResourceT` monad transformer, use `runResourceT`. The resulting code:

```
bss <- liftIO . runResourceT . lazyConsume . requestBody $ r
bss :: [ByteString]
```

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, the new version of Scotty (0.2.0) has a 'jsonData' method to do this for you. Thanks for using!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer won't actually work due to the way `lazyConsume` works. It will always return an empty list. You need to consume the data *before* exiting `ResourceT` if you're using `lazyConsume`.

As an alternative, here's how to strictly consume the bytestring and return it:

```
rawRequestBody :: Request -> IO B.ByteString
rawRequestBody req = mconcat <$> runResourceT (requestBody req $$ consume)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally work for me, adapted from jhickner's

```
rawRequestBody req = mconcat <$> (requestBody req $$ consume)
```